# Calculate federal withholding based on number of dependents

Tags: united-states, withholding, paycheck

How would you determine the exact federal withholding for a paycheck based on number of dependents in the United States? Is there a formula or a specific percentage of your gross based of number of dependents?

Comment: https://www.paycheckcity.com/calculator/salary/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The number of withholdings you have is based on your [W-4](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw4.pdf), of which your number of dependents is a factor, but not the only one.  Whether you're married, whether your spouse works, your income levels, etc all factor in.

Note that there is an [IRS calculator](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/irs-withholding-calculator) that you can use to get exact numbers.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize there were other factors that determine the amount.

Comment: Although if you can do arithmetic yourself -- or have a computer that can do arithmetic (which is usually the case for people who can access websites like Stack) -- the [updated notice 1036 is available](https://www.irs.gov/newsroom/2018-withholding-tables-now-available)